# How can I apply styles for multiple platforms without duplicating code in Android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My Android app supports back to API level 15 and targets API Level 21. For one style I want to add in attributes that were added in v16 and then added in v21. Is there a better way to do this other than duplicating the v16 attributes in v21?  With the code below, v21 devices will not have the font family applied from the v16 style.

**values/styles**

```
<style name="message" parent="message_base" />

<style name="message_base">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">36sp</item>
</style>
```

**values-v16/styles**

```
<style name="message" parent="message_base">
    <!-- Attribute introduced in v16 -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>
```

**values-v21/styles**

```
<style name="message" parent="message_base">
    <!-- Attribute introduced in v21 -->
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

**layout/view**

```
...
<TextView 
    style="@style/message" 
    android:text="@string/my_message" />
...
```

I kept the sample code very simple but imagine a lot more attributes used in the base style and maybe the v16 style that would have to be duplicated.

Comment: You did the best way. What else you want? Whatever styles you want in different API levels you have to write in that API's styles.xml file.

Comment: I am hoping for a method where I do not have to duplicate all of the v16 styles in the v21 styles.  I hate to make this sound web'ish but I would like Android to merge all of the applicable styles in a cascading effect.  In the example above, all of the v16 styles would have to be reimplemented in the v21 styles. That could cause a lot of extra code.